# What causes these plume features on Delta IV Heavy?

Tags: exhaust, combustion, delta-iv-heavy, plume

Just catching up on the Jan 19th launch of NROL-71 on board the Delta IV Heavy and I noticed these *very* prominent features in the exhaust plumes, beginning around the time the centre core is throttled down at about T+45s ([26:45 in this footage](https://youtu.be/DxjaRK2S7fw?t=1605)) and continuing for around 15 seconds.

I'm used to seeing some small flashes in the plumes that I assume are due to mixture ratio and combustion inconsistencies; is this the case here? Is it related to the throttling to partial-thrust mode of the core booster?

These seemed especially large and noticeable, but perhaps I just haven't been very observant in the past:

[image]

Comment: The RS-68A engine uses an ablative liner in the nozzle for cooling; my guess is that the yellow flashes are (carbon-rich?) bits of the ablative coming out.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Yeah good call - maybe the timing with the throttle-down is a coincidence and it's actually just when the ablative reaches a critical temperature...